# Swift Mailer dont always send to the ->setTo()

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I'm using Swift Mailer with Symfony 2.8 and having many bundles (1 per website).
I'm working with multiple site symfony/apps/site1, symfony/apps/site2, etc...

In config.yml I have no swiftmailer.delivery_address because in all my ContactHandler I set it manually Swift_Message::newInstance()->setTo()

In config_dev.yml I have swiftmailer.delivery_address: charly@toto.com

Considering all website are browse with www.webiste.com/ (always without app_dev.php) sometimes I receive email on charly@toto.com.

Can someone explain this behavior ?

In each config.yml (1 per website)

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: "smtp"
    host: "SSL0.OVH.NET"
    username: "postmaster@mysite.com"
    password: "**************"
```

In my main config_dev.yml

```
swiftmailer:
    delivery_address: charly@toto.com
```

Comment: Are you sending emails from console or directly from handler? Please, show swifmailer config.

Comment: I'm using the pool, a cron use console : */5 * * * * www-data php /home/symfony/bin/console swiftmailer:spool:send --env=prod --message-limit=50